# Is CC-BY the least strict CC license for my open source project?

Tags: licensing, cc-by

I have been working on an open source software. The software is in its final stages of testing and I will soon publish it under a CC license. I would like to release it under the least strict license (to provide users full access to do whatever they wish to it).

**My question:**

Is the CC-BY license the best license to use if I want to release it under no conditions or rules?

Comment: Relevant information: CC-BY is an attribution license

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The use of Creative Commons licenses for software is not recommended.](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_use_a_Creative_Commons_license_for_software.3F)  The CC licenses do not address concerns specific to software (such as the source code/object code relationship, or patent issues), and are incompatible with most open-source software licenses.

If you want to license your software "with no conditions or rules", you probably want either:

- [The Creative Commons Public Domain Dedication](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) (which [is suitable for use with software](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F))
- The [Do What The Fuck You Want To Public License](http://www.wtfpl.net/about/)

"Releasing into the public domain" has the problem that not all jurisdictions permit you to simply abandon your copyright to a work; to get around this, CC-0 and WTFPL both retain copyright while relinquishing all rights to the greatest extent permissible by law; of the two, CC-0 is probably the better written.

If you want to retain the requirement of being attributed for your work, you want one of the highly-permissive licenses such as the [three-clause BSD license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_.28.22Revised_BSD_License.22.2C_.22New_BSD_License.22.2C_or_.22Modified_BSD_License.22.29) or the [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License).  These are similar to CC-BY, but are designed for the needs of software.

Comment: Not sure if your concerns really apply to CC-BY, or only to CC-BY-SA.

Answer (score 3):

CC-BY still demands proper attribution. While some jurisdiction ask for that anyways, it is not everywhere the case. [Public Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_domain) (with sources included) or [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/about/cc0) are the most permissive options. They demand basically nothing.